# redirect_to append parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to append some parameters to redirect_to

```
redirect_to new_registration_path(:uid => params[:uid], :c_id => params[:c_id]), notice: 'Some msg!'
```

But for some reason I'm only getting the first one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify "I'm only getting the first one" - what does the redirected URL look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a `:c_id` to your `new#registrations` route (at `routes.rb`).

Assuming that you are using Devise, you can do something like that:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/new(/:uid(/:c_id))' => 'registrations#new', as: :new_registration
end
```

so, a `new_registration_path(1, 2)` will produce a `/new/1/2`, a `new_registration_path(1)` will produce a `/new/1` and a `new_registration_path`, without arguments, will produce a `/new`